# Re-rendering entire flat list vs current item, onViewableItemsChanged

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, use-state, flatlist

I have a problem when I update the state in my flat list that renders my Posts. I am trying to pause / play videos (think Tik tok) based on current visible index. Got it to work but the issue is I am currently re-rendering my entire flat list instead of just the current item which is causing performance issues. For functional, it seems like using usememo could be a solution. Does anybody have code / experience with onViewableItemsChanged and setting state for the current visible index where they get the current item to re-render (video) vs the entire flat list. Also code for pausing in post is in the video component I have paused = {props currentvisibleindex != props.index || paused}.